# Grails safe way to execute more queries after Hibernate exception?

Tags: hibernate, grails

In my service I'm expecting a certain kind of exception (`DataIntegrityViolationException`) that is the result of a unique constraint on the database preventing an insert. This is OK and can actually happen. I've been playing with the Grails console to get the correct type of exception in order to go on from there. However, I get this message:

```
org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null id in   
<my-domain-class> entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)
```

Now I'm not sure how to continue after that. Even when this specific error occurs I need to perform some deletes in other tables - basically I assume that the insert worked and the code just continues from there.

Is that safe - from a Hibernate point of view - after this kind of error? What do I have to do to get into a consistent state so that further calls into a different service (but still the same HTTP request) can correctly execute HQL statements?

*edit*

Basic workflow:

- Service A tries to insert into database
- No matter if that succeeds or fails (unique violation), service A shall call service B
- Service B performs a few selects using different domains and then one important delete
- The controller returns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The session may be in an invalid state after such an exception. Any subsequent persistence operations should be performed with a new session. You can open a new session in Grails with:

```
SomeDomainClass.withNewSession {
  // code that uses the new session goes here
}
```

Comment: How does that interfere with the case where no exception occurs? FYI: I added a short description of how the application works in this scenario

Answer (score 0):

There is a couple of things that you can try here, not 100% sure either will fix your issue but they should be easy enough to try.

1. You can add a unique validation to the field(s) that you're receiving an error on or custom validation to check before attempting to persist. [Grails Validation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#validation)
2. You could try to [Discard](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/discard.html) the object after the error occurs.